# Performance tuning with Innodb engine

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I am loading a table with million rows and 500 column in memory  using select * query , first I count total number of rows then select 100000 rows per query. my machine configuration is as follows

OS - Ubuntu
   RAM - 68 GB
   CPU - 32
   DataBase - Mysql 5.5

now after searching for a whole day I figured out following innodb configuration in my.cnf
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=50000M
    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=4000M
    #innodb_log_file_size=25M
    innodb_log_buffer_size=8000M
    sort_buffer=2000M
    thread_concurrency=32
    #record_buffer=128M
    query_cache_type=2
    tmp_table_size=1G
    innodb_force_recovery = 4

with this configuration my load time was **3.17 minute** . and with default innodb it was **8.3 minute**. if I remove # from above commented configuration mysql do not restart on my machine . Now I want to know can I reduce this load time upto 1 minute ?

thanks in advance .

Comment: it will be also good, if you properly normalize the tables and apply proper indexing

Comment: hi PravinS , i have made an index on primary key column . i dont know too much about normalizing tables . among these 500 column primary key column are date , time rest 498 are prices for different stocks ,so on normalization should I make 498 different tables having date,time,price column will that work faster ? thanks.

Comment: as you have 500 columns in single table, it will be better if you create multiple tables according to your requirement(with normalization) and can apply indexing, then you can use joins to fetch the required data